# Decorate imported functions for profiling in scalene

Tags: python, scalene

What is the best way to profile a helper function in a python script with scalene?

With memory_profiler I can do something like (pseudo code):

```
from memory_profiler import profile
import module
module.helper_function = profile(module.helper_function)

import function_using_helper_function

function_using_helper_function()
```

Which would give me a memory profile of helper_function line by line. Using profile() in scalene or scalene_redirect_profile() will not tag the helper_function to be included in profiling output.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```py
from scalene import scalene_profiler

@profile
def some_function():
  print("Do nothing")

scalene_profiler.start()

some_function()

scalene_profiler.stop()
```